# Prove that the function f is continuous

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Prove that $f(x)=x(1-x)$ is continuous if $f:([0,1),d_∗)→([0,1),d_{usu})$ where $d_∗(x,y)=\min\{|x-y|,1-|x-y|\}$.

It must be proved that for every $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that
$$d_*(x_0,x)\leq \delta \longrightarrow d_{usu}(f(x_0),f(x)) \leq \epsilon $$

My attempt
Suppose that $d_*(x_0,x)=|x_0-x| \leq \delta$ then

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|f(x_{0})-f(x)|&=|x_0(1-x_0)-x(1-x)|  \\
&=| x_0-x_0^2-x+x^2| \\
&=| (x_0-x)-(x_0^2-x^2)| \\
&\leq   |x_0-x|+|x_0-x| |x_0+x| \\
&\leq   \delta + 2 \delta \\
&=  3 \delta
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Thus, considering $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ it is fulfilled.

Now if $d_*(x_0,x)=1-|x_0-x| \leq \delta$ then
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|x_0-x| & \leq |x_0+x| \\
-|x_0+x| & \leq -|x_0-x| \\
1-|x_0+x| & \leq 1-|x_0-x| \leq \delta \\
 -1-|x_0+x|  & \leq \delta-2 \leq \delta
\end{split}
\end{equation}

then

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|f(x_0)-f(x)|&=| x_0(1-x_0)-x(1-x)| \\
&=|  x_0-x_0^2-x+x^2| \\
&=| (x_0-x)-(x_0^2-x^2)| \\
& \leq |x_0-x|+|x_0-x| |x_0+x| \\
& \leq  -|x_0-x|(-1-|x_0+x|) \\
& \leq  (\delta -1)(\delta) \\
& \leq  \delta^2- \delta \\
& \leq \delta^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Thus considering $\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon}$ is satisfied.

I would like to hear your opinions to know if my arguments are correct?

Comment: There seems to be a big flaw: from $(a\leqslant b)$ and $(c\leqslant d)$ you can't conclude that $(ac\leqslant bd)$.

Comment: Also I have a suggestion: you could begin to prove that $g\colon x\mapsto x$ is continuous (less complicated than $f$).

Comment: I do not understand where the fault lies.

Comment: You have
$\begin{cases}
\hfill -|x_0-x|&{}\leqslant\delta-1,\\
-1-|x_0+x|&{}\leqslant\delta.
\end{cases}$
From this you deduced that $-|x_0-x|\mathbin.(-1-|x_0+x|)\leqslant(\delta-1)\delta$.
Problem is: the two left-side members are $\leqslant0$. (Counter)example:
$-2\leqslant-1$ and $-3\leqslant1$ but $(-2)\mathbin.(-3)\leqslant (-1)\mathbin.1$ doesn't hold.

Comment: I understand. but I don't know how to use your suggestion.

Comment: 1°) $f$ is $h\circ g$ for some continuous
$h\colon\big([0\mathbin,1\mathclose[; |\mathbin\cdot|\big)\to\big([0\mathbin,1\mathclose[; |\mathbin\cdot|\big)$.
2°) We have $d_*\leqslant|\mathbin\cdot|$.

Comment: but $g:x↦x$ is not continous with $g:([0,1[,d_*)→([0,1[, d_{usu})$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142275/discussion-between-jp-boucheron-and-marco-roys).